# Annotating C# code in arbitrary levels without obfuscating the code too much?

Tags: c#

I'm looking for the best way to do the following in C#.

Say I have a certain set of instructions:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
if (a==b) {return;}
...
```

I need to get some information per instruction or sets of instructions. So I annotate the code, roughly as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine("a");
int a = 1;
Console.WriteLine("a");
int b = 2;
Console.WriteLine("if");
if (a==b) {
 Console.WriteLine("ret");
  return;}
...
```

Now suppose I need to have much more complete information about each instruction, actually several classes with some methods, and I want to even pass some information to those classes. Annotating the code like that certainly obfuscates the code to a point where it's practically unreadable. Imagine lots of prints in-between instructions, for instance.

My question, finally, is: is there a way (would `[Attributes]` help here?) to annotate code with arbitrary levels of complexity of the annotations, without cluttering it? I can imagine something like attributes, which would look like

```
[Class.variable("a")]
int a = 1;
[Class.variable("a")]
int b = 2;
[Class.instruction("if")]
if (a==b) {
  [Class.instruction("ret")]
  return;}
...
```

while each class does a lot of stuff? If the above example with atts work, could someone give me an example of how it would work "for real" and not in pseudocode?

Thanks very much.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: You can't add attributes to individual pieces of code, only to assemblies, types, and members. You can't add attributes to lines of code.

Comment: @Lasse. Maybe if you tell me what part is not clear I could try to rephrase? What I meant to say was "it would work like" attributes, but now I know it can't be attributes. I don't mind *how* I annotate the code, I just need a short concise way to do it. Think of it as "debugging printfs" on steroids.

Comment: Well, I'm wondering what the problem is that you're trying to solve. There is no way you can get an ordinary program to output every "line" it executes in any fashion without adding code to every line, but regardless of that, *which problem are you trying to solve*? Let me rephrase... Obviously something has happened that made you look into doing this. What was that something? I'm asking because what you're asking for is not really possibly, but perhaps if we knew what your underlying problem was, we could suggest an alternate route to solving it.

Comment: If it's debugging you're interested in, printing between each statement isn't an optimal approach.  If an error occurs that you're interested in and your goal is to find out where the code was at when the error occured, the thrown Exception's StackTrace property will contain the line number that the exception was thrown from, as long as the PDB file is present (and for debugging, it should be).

Comment: What do you mean by annotate? The first example you give does not annotate, but instead executes code.

What is the purpose of your annotation? Debuging, commenting, automatic code analysis, logging, or something else?

Comment: I'm finishing a paper on the asymptotics of certain cache-oblivious algorithms. I decided to annotate the code and generate a DAG on certain instructions I deem interesting to have a pretty pic and not just mathematics. Generating the graph is ok, except it adds a lot of garbage code to the main algo. Does C# have a way to minimize that code, without creating and assigning new classes?

Comment: Let me re-iterate my original comment(s). You can't attach attributes to individual lines of code, only to assemblies, types, and members. If you need to get output from every line executed of some piece of code, you're unfortunately left with the job of changing all those lines of code to outputting whatever you need output *in addition* to whatever those lines of code were supposed to do in the first place. Note: **this comment is because you tagged your question C#**. If your question would be more general for .NET, you might be able to do this using the .NET debugging interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read the code by some other program you are writing (to generate the graph), I think your best be is using comments, possibly a “special” kind of them like `//:`, or something.

I would usually advise against parsing source code by yourself, but I think it's the only way here. Although Mono might be of help here: it's compiler is open source and you can use it for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are debugging your code, then it could be useful to set brakepoints and to configure the "When Hit.." item of the brakepoints context menu. This one lets you print out a text to the Output Window without breaking code the execution.

Comment: Or may be just setting an ordinary breakpoint and then executing the problematic code step by step is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

you can't use attributes to decorate statements, not really sure that there's a clean way to log statements as you envision. what are you trying to accomplish with this level of verbose logging?